# How to undo when code collapses into an ellipsis?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I accidentally hit a key combination which collapsed my code to a yellow ellipsis symbol.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to **undo** it?
There is no button or symbol on the left side that I can click. Clicking, double-clicking, right-clicking on the ellipsis doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The collapsing of code blocks like that is referred to as "Code Folding".

The shortcuts for folding:

- OSX: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>
- Windows:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Unfolding:

- OSX: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
- Windows:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

If you have no text selected it will fold/unfold the code block the cursor is currently in.

[More info](http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-code-folding/)

Comment: I just ran into this problem myself and this answer helped but it was the other way for me on Sublime for Windows. `Ctrl + Shift + [` folded the text and `Ctrl + Shift ]` unfolded it.

Comment: Works on Linux too, with same key combo as Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try Edit > Code Folding > Unfold ?